# Attach different CSS styles on a node basing on publishing date or other PHP properties

Tags: nodes, theming

I want to attach a different CSS style to a node, basing on the node publishing date or some PHP properties.
What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are asking the wrong question. The question you should have asked is "how do I add a class on a node depending on some properties?". Using different set of CSS files to control styling a an element is just a no-no.

The answer to the correct question depends on whether you are targeting Drupal 6 or Drupal 7:

- On Drupal 6, you will generally have to implement the logic your own node template;
- On Drupal 7 (or on Drupal 6 if you are using an intelligent base theme like Zen), you would implement a `hook_preprocess_node()` in your theme and add classes to the `'classes_array'` variable

Comment: I agree about the `hook_preprocess_node` business.

Comment: You're right. I meant to say class. I'm using d6 so I guess i will have to just implement it on the template file

Answer (score 1):

Create a module, then in the

```
hook_init()
```

do your php calculations and include css with

```
drupal_add_css()
```

and js with

```
drupal_add_js().
```